# Share hidden values from one page to the next via a session

Tags: php, html

I have a some hidden values in one page. I want to create a session and navigate with the hidden fields to the next page or another page and access the hidden values.

How can I do that? Please give me an example.

Comment: can you provide a code sample for what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<form action="blah.php">
<input type="hidden" name="the_value" value="content" />
```

Then do the following in php:

```
<?
session_start(); // Start the session

$_SESSION['the_value'] = $_POST['the_value'];
?>
```

Now you have the value stored in the session. Be *careful* if you want to save this to MySQL. You need to sanitize the string first!